# Refresh button duplicate the datagridview data

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have problem when i try to refresh data in `datagridview`. Am using `MySQL` database. On every click on `Reload` button my old data is duplicated in grid. I try to set `datagridview.DataSource = null` also try to `Refresh` datagrid and also try to `Resert` binding source but nothing is happening.

**Check this:**

[image]

```
 public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.connStr = Properties.Settings.Default.connStr;
    }

    // Load
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectData();
    }

    // Seslect Data 
    public void SelectData()
    {                
        bs.DataSource = GetData("SELECT * FROM porudzbine");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    // Get Data
    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            adapter.Fill(dt);                                         
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return dt;
    }

    // Reload
    private void osveziListuPorudzbinaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
        bs.DataSource = GetData("SELECT * FROM porudzbine");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **field** called `dt` somewhere in your form (not shown in the post), which you are refilling (hence adding the records to the previously loaded records) on each `GetData` call.

Remove the field and use something like this:

```
// Get Data
private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    // ...
    return dt;
}
```